# qmake-generated Makefile for win32-g++ platform contains unix commands

Tags: c++, windows, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build a cross-compiler with Qt 5.4.1 to generate Raspberry Pi executables from a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine.

I'm using mingw64 and a gcc 4.9 cross-compiler for the Pi on the Windows machine and I am using the Qt 5.4.1 source. PATH points to the mingw64 binaries, the gcc 4.9 cross-compiler binaries, perl binaries, and %windir%\system32.

I use the following command to build the Qt cross-compiler:

```
configure.bat -platform win32-g++ -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ \
 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot \dev\qtxc\sysroot \
 -opensource -confirm-license -release -make libs -prefix d:\dev\qtxc \
 -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
```

Everything works fine until the very end when I get a few error messages containing Unix commands (again, I'm on a Windows machine in a Windows command prompt):

```
Running configuration tests...
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f arch.obj, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The file cannot be found
(...)
```

Then when I look at the generated Makefile, I can see that it erroneously defines Unix commands instead of Windows commands:

```
# Makefile for building: qt
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.4.1)
# Project:  qt.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: D:\dev\qtxc\qtbase\bin\qmake -o Makefile qt.pro

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = D:\dev\qtxc\qtbase\bin\qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
(...)
```

Then, of course, when I try to run `mingw32-make` as instructed in the output from the `configure` command, I get error messages related to the Unix commands that don't exist in Windows:

```
module-qtbase-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @test -d qtbase\ || mkdir -p qtbase\
    cd qtbase\ && $(QMAKE) D:\dev\qtxc\qtbase\qtbase.pro -o Makefile
    cd qtbase\ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
```

(`@test` doesn't work in Windows, of course).

I have tried modifying the `qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf` file to remove the Unix conditional definitions (seems like nonsense to have those in the win32 file anyway), forcing the definition of `QMAKE_SH` or `QMAKE_OS_WIN32`, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the only problem is the absence of `rm`, `cp` etc. on Windows, it's easy to get them (e.g. MSYS).

Comment: Sure. I can also replace the contents of the shell-unix.conf file where those variables come from with that of the shell-win32.conf file. But what I'd really like to do is to get it to generate properly on the first attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the very same problem myself while setting up a Gitlab-CI runner to compile a Qt project on windows.

Using the `-d` (debug) option on qmake (see [Running qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html)) I discovered that qmake looks for `sh` in PATH and then determines which command set to use by setting QMAKE_SH.

If you seach for `QMAKE_SH` in the debug output of qmake bottom up, you should find the line where qmake makes the above described decision. In case `sh` was found, searching further up will take you to the line where the actual path to `sh` is printed out.

Mine was found in the path to Git for Windows (`<path to git>\bin`), since there is a 'sh.exe' in the bin folder next to git.exe.

I found two solutions for my particular case:

1. Temporarily add the unix tools to the PATH. In Git for Windows 2.5.3 they are located in `<path to git>\usr\bin`.
2. Temporarily remove the path to sh from PATH. You can do this by issuing `SET PATH=%PATH:<path to remove>;=%` to the command line.

Comment: This worked for me, I actually had no reason to put Git in `PATH`, thanks.